# ERROR Error: [@RNC/AsyncStorage]: NativeModule: AsyncStorage is null

Tags: ios, react-native

I am creating a React Native iOS app, NOT using Expo. I installed AsyncStorage `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage` and am using it in my app as illustrated in the code below.

The problem is that I am getting the below error message. I have tried to fix the problem by taking the following steps, however the error persists. Can anyone advise how to fix the error?

**My code:**

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'

const authenticate = (token) => {
    setAuthToken(token)
    AsyncStorage.setItem('token', token)
}
```

**Steps I've taken to resolve error (all unsuccessful):**

1. quit the terminal and simulator, then rebuilt and restarted app
2. ran `npm start --reset-cache`
3. navigated to ios directory and ran `pod install`

**The error message:**

> ERROR  Error: [@RNC/AsyncStorage]: NativeModule: AsyncStorage is null.
> To fix this issue try these steps:
>
> ```
>   • Rebuild and restart the app.
>
>   • Run the packager with `--reset-cache` flag.
>
>   • If you are using CocoaPods on iOS, run `pod install` in the `ios` directory and then rebuild and re-run the app.
>
>   • If this happens while testing with Jest, check out docs how to integrate AsyncStorage with it: https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/advanced/jest
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when the library was not linked correctly or if auto-linking is not working. Try linking the library manually as explained [here](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install/).

`react-native link @react-native-async-storage/async-storage`

Comment: I tried manually linking but I'm getting an error `Invalid Podfile file: syntax error'` Do you know where in the Podfile to add the line `+ pod 'RNCAsyncStorage', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'` ? The docs say to add it below the last pod in the Podfile, but I don't understand where that is.

Comment: ```# Next line contains target platform settings
platform :ios, '8.0'
# Use dynamic Frameworks
use_frameworks!

# Target name
target 'MyApp' do
  # List of target dependencies
  pod 'ObjectiveSugar', '~> 1.1'
  pod 'ORStackView', '~> 3.0'
  pod 'RxSwift', '~> 2.6'
end```

You need to add your pod between ```target 'MyApp' do``` and ```end```

Here is an [example](https://riptutorial.com/cocoapods/example/19556/podfile-sample)